# How to search data from two tables using population in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose-populate

I have below schema for **User** and **Report Request** tables and using population to fetch and display Reported users list.

```
var user = new Schema({
    name : {type:String,required:[true,"name is required"]},
});

var report_request = new Schema({
    user_id : {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    reported_by_id : {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    reason : String,
});
```

But the problem is I have search filters in listing and can search reported users by name. So I want to do something like this:
report_request.find({'user.name': /Ruby/i});

```
id  Name    Reported By
1   Ruby    Mark
2   Johny   Ruby
```

I tried to do this but it is not working. So is their any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using population, you can issue a "sub-query" against the populated documents:

```
report_request.find()
              .populate({
                path  : 'user_id',
                match : { name : /Ruby/i }
              })
              .exec(...)
```

However, as far as I know, this will first retrieve *all* `repost_request` documents from the database and subsequently run a query against `user` to find the ones that match `/Ruby/i`.

So in terms of performance, this isn't a good solution. However, with the schema you have I think it's the *only* solution that can be performed with a single step.

Instead, you first need to find users that match the name, and use their id's to find the reports belonging to them:

```
user.find({ name : /Ruby/i }).exec(function(err, users) {
  var ids = users.map(function(user) { return user.id });
  request_report.find({ user_id : { $in : ids } }).exec(function(err, requests) {
  ...
  });
});
```

(I can't remember if `{ user_id : { $in : users } }` would work as well in Mongoose; if so, it would save you the additional `users.map()`)